# Selected rows on MySQL table on time slot

Tags: mysql, datetime

This is my *dotable* on **MySQL** database :

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
| sID          | sDate      | sHour    |
+--------------+------------+----------+
| 1440190025   | 2019-05-08 | 02:46:01 |
| 1440190019   | 2019-05-07 | 16:06:01 |
| 1440190017   | 2019-05-07 | 12:59:02 |
| 1440190013   | 2019-05-07 | 10:56:14 |
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

I need select on this *dotable* all rows included on this time slot :

```
18:00:00-00:00:00
```

with decreasing three hours to the start time ( *-3 hours on 18:00:00* ) and adding three hours to the final hour ( *+3 hours on 00:00:00* ) :

```
-3 18:00:00 >>> 15:00:00 
+3 00:00:00 >>> 03:00:00
```

I have tried this SQL query :

```
mysql> SELECT
    sID,
    sDate,
    sHour
FROM
    dotable
WHERE
    sHour BETWEEN ADDTIME(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('18:00:00-00:00:00', '-', 1) ,- 30000
    )
AND ADDTIME(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('18:00:00-00:00:00', '-', - 1),
    30000
);
+------------+------------+----------+
| sID        | sDate      | sHour    |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 1440190019 | 2019-05-07 | 16:06:01 |
+------------+------------+----------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

This output not show the **sID** with number **1440190025** though the value of **sHour** is included on slot time **15:00:00 - 03:00:00**.

Do anyone have an idea why?

My code below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotable`;
CREATE TABLE `dotable` (
  `sID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sHour` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of dotable
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('1440190013', '2019-05-07', '10:56:14');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('1440190017', '2019-05-07', '12:59:02');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('1440190019', '2019-05-07', '16:06:01');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('1440190025', '2019-05-08', '02:46:01');
```

Comment: You are forgetting that when you add 3 Hours to `24:00` the DATE will also change

Comment: This would probably be easier to code if the Date and Time were in one DateTime field. Then adding 3 hours would automatically move the date ahead as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok - thanks, but how to do resolve this?

Comment: Also as you are dealing with strings adding 3 hours to 24:00 makes 27:00 .... Which of course dont exist

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have changed 24:00 with 00:00 but not the row is empty

Answer (score 0):

I hope I was helpful.

```
mysql> SELECT
    sID,
    sDate,
    sHour
FROM
    `dotable`
WHERE
    sHour >= ADDTIME(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('18:00:00-00:00:00', '-', 1) ,- 30000
    )
OR sHour <= ADDTIME(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('18:00:00-00:00:00', '-', - 1),
    30000
);


+------------+------------+----------+
| sID        | sDate      | sHour    |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 1440190019 | 2019-05-07 | 16:06:01 |
| 1440190025 | 2019-05-08 | 02:46:01 |
+------------+------------+----------+
2 rows in set
```